# Aplicando PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo un detalle de `Catalogo` que se llama `ProductoCatalogo` en el cual ingreso los productos que se van a vender, pero hay productos que tienen sus especificaciones como en el caso de la ropa tienen: Talla y Color, eso esta registrado en un maestro de Especificaciones que tiene la siguiente estructura:
Cabecera = tabla `Especificaciones` y Detalle = Tabla `Opciones` en `Especificaciones`  va Color y en `Opciones` va Rojo, Azul, Amarillo, etc. Lo mismo sucede para tallas.

Esta es la estructura de las tablas involucradas para obtener la información que deseo.

[image: Producto Catalogo]

La información que deseo obtener es la siguiente:

- ProductoCatalogoId
- Nombre del Producto
- Precio Venta
- Talla
- Color

Esto es lo que espero como resultado:

```
1 CAMISETA FERRARI 12.00 TALLA LETRA S COLOR ROJO
1 CAMISETA FERRARI 12.00 TALLA LETRA S COLOR AZUL
```

Para eso he elaborado la siguiente consulta en la cual le aplico un filtro por el nombre del producto. Como les dije tengo un maestro especificaciones es por eso que en NombreOpcion me sale las tallas y colores.

```
SELECT PC.ProductoCatalogoId, PC.ProductoId, P.Nombre, PC.PrecioVenta, 

EP.EspecificacionId, E.Nombre, EC.OpcionId, 
O.NombreOpcion
FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
JOIN Productos AS P ON P.ProductoId = PC.ProductoId
JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EP.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON E.EspecificacionId = EP.EspecificacionId
JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
JOIN Opciones AS O ON O.OpcionId = EC.OpcionId
WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%FERR%'
```

Que me arroja los siguientes datos.

[image: consulta]

Necesito separar las tallas y los colores para eso he improvisado con `PIVOT`, con el cual se ha podido poner los colores en la columna Color la cual se separo con `PIVOT`, pero no ha funcionado con Talla.

```
WITH Pruebas(ProductoCatalogoId, ProductoId, NombreProducto, PrecioVenta, 

EspecificacionId, Nombre, OpcionId, NombreOpcion) AS
    (SELECT PC.ProductoCatalogoId, PC.ProductoId, P.Nombre, PC.PrecioVenta, EP.EspecificacionId, E.Nombre, EC.OpcionId, 
O.NombreOpcion
FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
JOIN Productos AS P ON P.ProductoId = PC.ProductoId
JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EP.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON E.EspecificacionId = EP.EspecificacionId
JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
JOIN Opciones AS O ON O.OpcionId = EC.OpcionId
WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%FERR%')
SELECT * FROM PRUEBAS
PIVOT(MAX(NombreOpcion) FOR Nombre IN ([TALLA LETRA], [COLOR])) PVT
```

Me arroja la siguiente información.

[image: consulta 2]

Probando con pantalones

[image: pantalones]

No se si es la forma correcta o hay otra manera de obtener lo que necesito.
Credenciales para conectarse a la base de datos.

Server: den1.mssql4.gear.host User: negocio Pass: Ga33-47L1YC!

Gracias de antemano.
Saludos!

Comment: qué significa en este caso que el mismo producto tenga 2 colores?, es eso correcto?

Comment: Una camiseta puede haber en color: rojo, azul, blanco, si es correcto. Una camiseta del mismo modelo puede tener tallas S, M, L y colores rojo, azul, blanco. Uno como cliente escoje que color y talla comprar.

Comment: no veo ningún problema con lo que estás haciendo entonces...cualquier forma alternativa (yo usaría un `CASE`), sería más tema de preferencias que de performance

Comment: La talla me esta saliendo `null` en cambio los colores si se están poniendo en la separación.

Comment: pero es la misma talla para ambos colores?, es que tu modelo no acabo de entenderlo….qué pasa si además existiera la talla M?, qué resultado querrías en ese caso?

Comment: @Lamak Acabo de probar con pantalones que tienen varias tallas registrados tengo que cambiar esta parte `PIVOT(MAX(NombreOpcion) FOR Nombre IN ([TALLA NÚMERO], [COLOR])) PVT` y si llena las tallas y los colores pero primero a todos y luego repite el resultado con los colores entonces eso hace que se duplique el resultado y no me lo junta en una sola linea.

Comment: @Lamak puse el resultado de pantalones que tiene varias tallas en hilo inicial.

Comment: la verdad es que no comprendo cuál es el resultado que quisieras obtener. Puedes postear el resultado esperado?

Comment: `1 CAMISETA FERRARI 12.00 TALLA LETRA S COLOR ROJO`

Comment: @Lamak agregue lo que me pedías en el hilo inicial.

Comment: pero la camiseta tiene 2 colores?

Comment: @Lamak Si solo están registrados dos colores.

Comment: @Lamak Server: den1.mssql4.gear.host User: negocio Pass: Ga33-47L1YC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres mostrar esos 2 productos, ya acomodados por sus colores y sus tallas, quedaría algo así:

```
   SELECT distinct(PC.ProductoCatalogoId),
    P.Nombre,
    PC.PrecioVenta,
    PL.Product + ' ' + E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion
FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId 
INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
AND E.EspecificacionId = 2
INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT E.Nombre + ' ' + O.NombreOpcion AS 'Product'
    FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
    INNER JOIN Productos AS P ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
    INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
    INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
    INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
        AND E.EspecificacionId IN (5)
    INNER JOIN Opciones AS O ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId

    ) PL
    WHERE P.Nombre LIKE '%FERR%'
```

> El pantalon tiene diferentes tallas y precios, si tomas esas tallas y precios por color que tiene cada 1, obtendras muchos resultados, pero cada 1 con su precio, color, y talla ordenados, mientras que la camisa, tiene solo 1 talla y 2 colores.

En este caso debes de especificar el acomodo de tu campo nuevo, para esto debes de definir cual especificacionId = 2 (COLOR) y el especificacionId = 5 (TALLA LETRA) para tu camisa.

Espero y te sirva.

Comment: Modifique la respuesta

Comment: Estoy seguro que `AND E.EspecificacionId = 2` lo puedo mandar por parámetro al igual que  `AND E.EspecificacionId = 5` y de esa manera puedo buscar cualquier tipo de producto. Voy hacer la prueba.

Comment: Ricardo, Si tengo registrado en la tabla EspecificacionCatalogos las tallas y colores que tiene un producto como pantalon, camiseta. ¿Porque tengo que ponerle parámetros? me refiero a `AND E.EspecificacionId = 2` y `AND E.EspecificacionId IN (5)` no debería hacer eso ya que esos datos están registrados por cada producto.que ingreso al Catalogo.

Comment: Ricardo, me he dado cuenta que si es necesario mandarle esos parámetros para que haga la búsqueda que se necesita para un producto en especifico.